# How get section number when tableview get scrolled

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I want to change screen's navigation title based on tableview's section header, so how can I identify that which section is scrolling in tableview.

Answer (score 1):

`tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, willDisplay...` will not do the trick as it may be called before the next section is on the screen.
I suggest to use `UIScrollViewDelegate` method in pair with `tableView.indexPathsForVisibleRows`

```
extension MyViewController: UITableViewDelegate, UIScrollViewDelegate {
            
   func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
      let visibleIndices = tableView.indexPathsForVisibleRows ?? []
      let lowestVisibleSection = visibleIndices.map({$0.section}).max() ?? 0
      debugPrint("I see \(lowestVisibleSection)")
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try to implement it like this:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, willDisplay cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    let position = cell.convert(CGPoint.zero, to: tableView)
    if let indexPath = tableView.indexPathForRow(at: position) {
        let section = indexPath.section
        print("The section is \(section)")
    }
}
```